# check the response from ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery

I've made a function in which there is an ajax call but after getting the response it's always going to else part even if get the response as "invalid". Even I write the if else part after the result(in ajax itself) but not working. Please help me.

```
var res="";
var urlString="/maintenance/calculate_GMT.jsp?full_date="+new_date+"&country="+country+"&time_zone="+time_zone;

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache :false,
    async :false,
    url: urlString,
    success: function(result) {
         res=result;
    }
});

alert("res=============>"+res);
if(res=="invalid"){
    alert("Please enter the correct date time by checking the daylight savings time(DST)");
} else {
    abc(res);
}
```

**Function abc :**

```
function abc(result){
        document.getElementById("hide").value = result;
        var data =document.getElementById("hide").value;
        data=$.trim(data);
        alert("data====>"+data);
        var arr=data.split(" ");
        alert(arr[0]);
        alert(arr[1]);
        $("#gmt_date").val($.trim(arr[0]));
        $("#gmt_time").val($.trim(arr[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the res  Trim the data

**TRIM**

```
res=$.trim(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your javascript like so...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
        cache :false,
        async :false,
        url: urlString,
        success: function(result) {
            res=result;

        alert("res=============>"+res);
        if(res=="invalid"){
            alert("Please enter the correct date time by checking the daylight savings time(DST)");
            }
            else {
                abc(res);
            }

    }
});
```

Comment: i have already done this but still its always coming in else part

Comment: What is the value of the res variable being returned?

Comment: my mistake the res is coming with the spaces i have trimmed the res.now its working properly thanks for help